# Event log tabulation table

Tags: r, data-mining

So I am not sure which if any tabulation function to use within **R** for my problem.  Basically I have a set of Data (an event log) with various user-ids as the reference and then specific products for each user for each event.  I want to create a tabulated table (products x products) for anytime a specific user has purchased two different products the corresponding table gets a plus +1.... i.e.

```
user1  prod2
user2  prod1
user1  prod1
```

so basically entry (prod1,prod2) = 1 (and (prod2,prod1) = 1, as well due to symmetry).... diagonals will either be 1's or 0's not super important.... I could write a loop for this potentially to run through the data but if there is a function already I would love to know.

Comment: Can you please provide some data?  Are you looking for pairwise tabulation or something more basic like `table()`?

Comment: pairwise tabulation i think. row (i, j) = (number of users who bought both i and j)

Answer (score 3):

Read in the data; use `xtabs` to convert it to a user (rows) by product (columns) table; take the cross product of the table with itself and reduce any element that is more than 1 to 1:

```
# read in data
Lines <- "user1  prod2
user2  prod1
user1  prod1
user3  prod2
user4  prod3
user4  prod2
user5  prod4
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)

# compute required matrix
pmin(crossprod(xtabs(~., DF)), 1)
```

The last line returns:

```
       V2
V2      prod1 prod2 prod3 prod4
  prod1     1     1     0     0
  prod2     1     1     1     0
  prod3     0     1     1     0
  prod4     0     0     0     1
```